# Replace numeric elements in a vector with character elements in R

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector containing elements of different values

```
m<-c(0,1,3,1,0,4,6,3,7,1)
```

I want to replace each unique element with a particular character element: 0 with "NA", 1 with "blue", 3 with "green", 4 with "purple", 6 with "pink", 7 with "yellow" and get the output in a different vector

The output should look like this:

```
>m2
"NA","blue","green","blue","NA","purple","pink","green","yellow","blue"
```

Comment: Read about `?factor` function.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go...

```
dplyr::recode(m, "1" = "blue", "3" = "green", "4" = "purple", "6"="pink", "7"="yellow",.default = "NA")
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R you can use

```
m2 <- factor(m, labels = c("NA", "blue", "green", "purple", "pink", "yellow"))
```

Output

```
# [1] NA     blue   green  blue   NA     purple pink   green  yellow blue  
# Levels: NA blue green purple pink yellow
```